# Produto exibido seja o menor dentro do grupo (Criteria)

Tags: java, hibernate, session, criteria

Tenho uma função no sistema que estou desenvolvendo que retorna uma lista de lotes em que a quantidade do lote seja maior que zero, buscando pelo nome do produto (chave estrangeira). Até esse ponto consegui. Ao fazer a pesquisa ele me retorna todos o lotes daquele produto que digitei o nome.

Porém tenho vários lotes do mesmo produto, queria realizar um filtro para que somente fosse exibido o lote que a validade é a menor entre eles, travando a opção do usuário escolher um lote do produto, sendo que tem outro que a validade é menor e poderia ser liberado logo.

```
public List<Lote> lotePorNomeMedicamento(String nome) {
    Session session = this.manager.unwrap(Session.class);

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Lote.class)
            // fazemos uma associação (join) com medicamento e nomeamos como "m"
            .createAlias("medicamento", "m");

    // acessamos o nome do medicamento associado ao pedido pelo alias "m",
    // criado anteriormente
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("m.nome", nome, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

    // retringir lotes com quantidade zero
    criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("quantidade",0));

    // restringir lotes para o valor exibido seja o menor do grupo
    criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("validade", value))


    return criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("lote")).list();
}
```

Esse é o código pensei em usar o Restrictions.gt na validade, porém o valor dessas validade tem ser a menor entre os três.

Ex:

> (Lote - Produto - Validade - Quantidade)
>
> Lote01 - Produto01 - 01/02/2016 - 10
>
> Lote02 - Produto01 - 03/02/2016 - 10
>
> Lote03 - Produto01 - 08/02/2016 - 10

O resultado que seria exibido seria o Lote01 apenas, pois é lote do mesmo produto que a validade é a menor entre eles. Alguma sugestão? E possível fazer isso usando o Criteria?

Classe Lote

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
@Entity
@Table (name = "lote")
public class Lote implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String lote;
private String marca;
private Integer quantidade;
private Date validade;
private Medicamento medicamento;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String lotePesq;

@NotBlank
@Id
public String getLote() {
    return lote;
}

public void setLote(String lote) {
    this.lote = lote;
}

@NotBlank
public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}

@Min(value = 0, message = "deve ser maior que zero.")
public Integer getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}

public void setQuantidade(Integer quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}

@NotNull
public Date getValidade() {
    return validade;
}

public void setValidade(Date validade) {
    this.validade = validade;
}

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
public Medicamento getMedicamento() {
    return medicamento;
}

public void setMedicamento(Medicamento medicamento) {
    this.medicamento = medicamento;
}   

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((lote == null) ? 0 : lote.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Lote other = (Lote) obj;
    if (lote == null) {
        if (other.lote != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lote.equals(other.lote))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Faz o seguinte

```
ProjectionList projections = Projections.projectionList();
projections.add(Projections.min("validade"))
criteria.setProjection(projections)
```

Comment: Tive que utilizar assim: criteria.add((Criterion) Projections.min("validade")); porém é exibido esse erro: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.criterion.AggregateProjection cannot be cast to org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion - Tive que fazer o cast porque é exigido pelo codigo.

Comment: Editei o código, dessa forma ele fica mais elegante.

Comment: Alterado pelo seu código, porém está exibindo este erro: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to br.com.modelo.Lote - Coloquei na pergunta a classe Lote como fiz o mapeamento. Isso acontece sempre que digito cada letra do nome, pois o campo e do tipo autocomplete do primefaces.

Comment: Esse é um problema de conversão de tipos, que foge do escopo da pergunta original. Caso minha resposta esteja correta, por favor marque ela e crie outra pergunta informando os mapeamentos que você fez, de tela e bean do JSF. No entanto lendo a exceção parece que você está passando um objeto temporal no lugar de um lote.

Comment: Vou procurar mais detalhes sobre no novo problema! E posto a solução junto com a confirmação da sua resposta!

Comment: A sua solução aparentemente não resolveu meu problema, pois está gerando conflito de alguma forma com a minha classe de conversão de objeto para string.